# Groovy: group trades by portfolio with string search

Tags: string, groovy

I'm not programmer but I need your help because I was left with IT system with no IT support, so I need to change code by myself. So sorry for stupid question, your help will be highly appreciated, i hope it is not too difficult...
I have code

```
trades.groupBy {
  data.findRecord('Portfolios', it.portfolioId).getFieldValue('Name').toString().substring(0,4) 
}
```

which takes first 4 symbols of portfolio name and groups trades. I need new rule:

1. if name contains `|` sign, find number of this sign in the string (n) and take n-2 first signs
2. if name doesn't contain `|` take all signs of this string.

For example  I have portfolio names

```
14717_81   
14717_81 | John  
14717_78 | Jane
```

So first two trades will be grouped

Comment: add some test data and desired output

Comment: the `trades` variable contains "portfolio names"?

Comment: @injecteer Yes, its one of the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of my solution is pretty simple.

I use `split()` on each "trade", take the 1st part of it and make the list unique:

```
def trades = '''\
14717_81
14717_81 | John
14717_78 | Jane'''.readLines()

trades = trades*.split( /\s*\|\s*/ )*.first().unique()

assert trades == ['14717_81', '14717_78']
```

Then you can use the prepared `trades` collection in the `groupBy` method of yours.